# Cyanogenmod's wiki moved, should we edit our deeplinks?

Tags: discussion, editing

Recently, CyanogenMod moved its Wiki and created an empty one at the current location:

[Source](https://plus.google.com/117962666888533781522/posts/25s15yc6vep) post from +CyanogenMod on Google Plus.

Alas, this means that old links to content don't work anymore. There's also not the slightest hint about the oldwiki:

Example here is a deeplink to Galaxy Ace' full update guide:

- broken: [http://**wiki**.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Samsung_Galax...](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Ace%3a_Full_Update_Guide)
- working: [http://**oldwiki**.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Samsung_Galax...](http://oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Ace%3a_Full_Update_Guide)

It's not clear if old content will become available at it's current link position again, especially for old devices like the Galaxy Ace that are only officially supported until CM7.

Should we act and edit all deeplinks to wiki.cyanogenmod and change them to oldwiki... to reflect this change?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, search through all posts and replace deeplinks to wiki.cyanogenmod to point to oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org for the sake of a good user experience.

And here's a [local search](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki.cyanogenmod.com) ([and another](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki.cyanogenmod.org)) or a [custom Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:android.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+%22wiki.cyanogenmod%22) to find those posts.

If you edit, **be sure** to let the link **end** in **.org**, because oldwiki.cyanogenmod.com is not available, only .org is.

Comment: The local search finds about 20 posts  while Google finds about 200 links.

Answer (score 0):

The Cyanogen Mod community should be notified, in particular any site manager/mod, so that whomever maintains the links on the site can update with an appropriate solution on their end (i.e. one that splits users between the old version and the new, or that performs a more user/SEO-friendly redirect).

Comment: I have already notified both persons in charge, but to no avail. Well, seems that's also an answer.

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not worth the hassle.

Comment: No point in doing it manually, maybe if it could be done automatically? Also, most of the new wiki's have been re-made, and so the links now work.